# How to get int and then string from terminal input in C++

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and I am trying to get an int and then a string just like in the code below:

If I switch the order - get the string first and then the int - it works fine, but doing it in this order doesn't work.

When I enter the age it just skips the input for the name.
Why does this happen? And how can I fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age;
    string name;

    cout << "Enter age : ";
    cin >> age;
    cout << "Age : " << age << endl;

    cout << "Enter name : ";
    getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Name : " << name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's a Java question but it's the exact same problem, and the solution should work just as well.

Comment: There's also a [C++ dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567291/why-does-stdgetline-skip-input-after-a-formatted-extraction).